# Expo App Runs on Expo Go App but shows Unmatched Route Error on APK

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building an App using Expo and I am facing a weird situation

When testing on Expo Go App it runs smoothly but after I build the APK and run on my Adnroid Device it gives the Error Unmatched Route. Please see image below [image: Unmatched Route Error on Startup after I build APK]

I am using Expo Router for the Navigation and feel that is where the problem is from

See app.json below

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "2kshop",
    "slug": "2kshop",
    "scheme": "2kshop",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./app/assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "dark",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./app/assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.twokshop.twokshop",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "cee8750b-df5e-4083-b48e-99130dbcf071"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As a temporay fix I creates a new file named [...unmatched] and used the UseEffect hook to redirect to the index.js

Please see code below

```js
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";

export default function Unmatched() {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.push("");
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```